# newly added field not showing validation error when adding a new address

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, opencart

Im customizing my opencart to add a telephone field at my checkout. im using a one page checkout extension which works good apart from the validation of the phone number.

The problem is when i select the option to a new address it validates all other fields and shows the relevant error below the field. But in the telephone field the error is thrown when i check through firebug, but not below the filed.

I did exactly what is done in other fields

below is the HTML code for the field

```
<tr>
<td><label for="telephone"><span class="required">*</span> Phone Number</label>  </td>
<td><input type="text" name="telephone_2" required class="large-field" /><br /></td>
</tr>
```

JS code

```
$('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address input[name=\'address_1\']').live('blur', function() {
    valiform<?php echo $type; ?>("address_1","");
});

$('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address input[name=\'address_1\']').live('focus', function() {
    errorremove<?php echo $type; ?>("address_1");
});

$('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address input[name=\'telephone_2\']').live('blur', function() {
    valiform<?php echo $type; ?>("telephone_2","");
});

$('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address input[name=\'telephone_2\']').live('focus', function() {
    errorremove<?php echo $type; ?>("telephone_2");
});

function valiform<?php echo $type; ?>(vname, othername){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=onecheckout/form/validate',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address input[name=\''+vname+'\']'+othername),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {                       
            if (json['error'][vname]) {
                errorremove<?php echo $type; ?>(vname);
                $('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address input[name=\''+vname+'\'] + br').after('<span id="error_'+vname+'" class="error">' + json['error'][vname] + '</span>');
            }
        }
    }); 
}

function errorremove<?php echo $type; ?>(vname) {
    if($('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address #error_'+vname)){
        $('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address #error_'+vname).remove();
    }
}
```

please check the below screenshot
[image]

can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: May be your selector is not correct. i mean `name=\'telephone_2\'` or `name=\'telephone\'`, or better if you could post your markup of your generated form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this HTML markup

```
<td><input type="text" name="telephone_2" required class="large-field" /><br /></td>
```

into

```
<td><input type="text" name="telephone_2" required class="large-field" /></td>
```

(so to remove the `<br />` tag) and then change this line in JS:

```
$('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address input[name=\''+vname+'\'] + br').after('<span id="error_'+vname+'" class="error">' + json['error'][vname] + '</span>');
```

into this:

```
$('#<?php echo $type; ?>-address input[name=\''+vname+'\']').after('<br /><span id="error_'+vname+'" class="error">' + json['error'][vname] + '</span>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just made the changes but still it doesn't appear. when i move from the fields in the form `POST http://localhost/index.php?route=onecheckout/form/validate` is being called at each instance where the errors are shown except for the telephone. I just checked the source code firefox but the the JS code i mentioned in my question isnt listed. Its a bit odd, becuase even `http://localhost/index.php?route=onecheckout/form/validate` is not visible in the source.

Comment: So your custom field is not even being validated? So the problem lies elsewhere and even before the error message should be displayed?

Comment: its being validated. It doesnt allow me to submit the form and the json error is shown through firebug as i mentioned in my question. The problem is it doesnt appear. if its not validated it would allow me to submit the form na. I need to show that error to the user

Comment: finally got it fixed. i have to add a new function along with ur suggested code.. thanks

Comment: You are welcome! What function did You add? Maybe it could be fine to post it here as Your own answer and accepting it since mine didn't solve the problem exactly :-)